# Access digits from integer value

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an `int` variable (`value1`).

```
 Int value1 =95478;
```

I want to take each digit of `value1` and insert them into an array (`array1`). Like this,

```
int[] array1 = { 9, 5, 4, 7, 8 };
```

No idea how this can be done. Any idea?

Comment: have you tried simple math for that? (div by 10, by 100, etc...)

Comment: OOO! your right! ...why didn't I think of that!

Comment: I didn't downvote but if you copy and paste your question title into google you get results that give pretty much the exact answer as faby.

Comment: What happend!.... 300 reputations from 197? Never knew about bonuses can be done here. :)))) Thankssss soooooooo much.

Comment: @Giliweed Looks like you earned 100 association bonus. Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/users/2059267/giliweed?tab=reputation

Comment: Yes, and not only this site. In crypto and scrutiny too.  I really thank SO for this. :))

Comment: What is the wanted behaviour for negative numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int[] array1 =  95478.ToString()
                .Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString()))
                .ToArray();
```

Comment: Going via `string` is roughly five times as slow as the mathematical way, not that it matters in most implementations but I thought it would be good to at least have it noted.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
    Int value1 =95478;
    List<int> listInts = new List<int>();
    while(value1 > 0)
    {
        listInts.Add(value1 % 10);
        value1 = value1 / 10;
    }
    listInts.Reverse();
    var result= listInts .ToArray();
```

this doesn't use strings

Answer (score 1):

The most optimal solution I could come up with:

```
public static class Extensions {
  public static int[] SplitByDigits(this int value) {
    value = Math.Abs(value); // undefined behaviour for negative values, lets just skip them
    // Initialize array of correct length
    var intArr = new int[(int)Math.Log10(value) + 1];
    for (int p = intArr.Length - 1; p >= 0; p--)
    {
      // Fill the array backwards with "last" digit
      intArr[p] = value % 10;
      // Go to "next" digit
      value /= 10;
    }
    return intArr;
  }
}
```

Is roughly double the speed of using a `List<int>` and reversing, roughly ten times faster and a tonne more memory efficient than using strings.

Just because you have a powerful computer you are not allowed to write bad code :)